# How can I deploy a git tag on Azure Websites from Bitbucket

Tags: node.js, git, azure, bitbucket

We are currently using git flow to develop our nodejs website running on Azure Websites.

The deployment works well with a branch (develop for example) but does not seem to checkout anything new if I specify a version tag (even forcing the synchronisation with BitBucket).

Any idea how I should be doing this as I really want to have the production website match a version?

Comment: Hi Pascal. Did you find a solution to this problem? Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I guess I should submit a pull request to github.com/projectkudu/kudu

Comment: I spoke with one of the developers on the Kudo project and I've raised on issue at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1435

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll follow the status of the issue thanks